# How can i make self updating list in python?

Tags: python

I wrote a function in python to find divisors and i want list as output (divisor(4) -> 1,2,4).

```
def divisors(n):
    i = 1
    while (i <= n):
        x = n % i
        if x == 0:
            a = []
            p = a.insert(0,i)
            print p
        i = i + 1
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"self updating"*, precisely? What output are you getting, and what do you expect instead?

Comment: What does your question have to do with the title? Currently, it is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: most changes on computer programs(maybe all of them) are causes of human instructions. yet i've not heard about a program which has a deep reflexive consciousness  - that can renew, update the instructions by itself (maybe himself/herself). if you write some loop instructions and give it to computer, it/he/she will process it. computers generally execute your commands - not the things decided by it/him/her. 

but if you want a program that spits out the divisors of an integer number - it is easy. `divisors = [i for i in (1, n) if n/i == n*1.0/i ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the variable a outside loop.

```
def deviser(n):
        a=[];
        i=1;
        while( i<= n):
                x=n%i;
                if( x == 0 ):
                        p = a.insert(0, i);
                        print i;
                i = i+1;
        return a;

>>> deviser(18)
1
2
3
6
9
18
[18, 9, 6, 3, 2, 1]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should initiate the list outside the while loop and then return the list:

```
def divisors(n):
     i = 1
     a = []
     while (i<=n):
         if n % i == 0:
             p = a.append(i)
             print p
         i += 1
     return a
```